# Is there a way to modify Gtk.EntryCompletion to limit the number of completions displayed?

Tags: python, gtk3

I've just begun exploring Gtk in Python after using Tkinter and the complexity is a bit overwhelming. I want to use EntryCompletion but I also want to limit the number of completion strings displayed and I have no idea how to go about this. I know from reading the [Gtk documentation for EntryCompletion](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryCompletion.html) that it uses CellLayout to modify the TreeView, but I really don't know what to do with that information. Also, I know from passing sufficiently large lists of strings to EntryCompletion that the popup will resize with a scrollbar rather than go off-screen. This is precisely the effect I want, but after a specified number of completion strings.